# Monogame - Level in a second script/ class

Tags: c#, monogame

I am new to monogame and I never worked with levels before.

Now to my question: is it possible to create a level in a second script/ class, so I can call/ initialize the new level e.g. on button press?
Because when I'm initializing the new level in the default script the script is getting pretty messy and large.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that it's possible to make a level creator in a new class. I would even recommend it if you're going to use multiple levels. But was that all you had to ask about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and surely recommended.
For an RPG for example it does make sense to have a separate class or script for each Level / area that defines the behaviour of NPCs or events you may trigger.

This keeps it clean and manageable when the game gets bigger.

I also recommend to build some kind of manager class that "sits" above all your level-classes and handles things like loading/switching levels or distributing player actions.
You may also take care about unloading level data when switching between them. It can be quite irritating if some fragments of the previous level are lying around somewhere and cause unexpected behaviour ;)

Comment: And can you tell me how I can "link" the script in the main script?

Comment: In my case, I use a static class "LevelManager". This class holds an instance of the current level. It also provides static methods like InteractWithNPC(string id) or InteractWithObject(string objectId). The manager passes those method calls to the current level instance. In the instance itself it is defined what to do with that input, like "if objectId = x then spawn enemy y"

all those level-classes implement an interface (ILevel), so my manager class only needs one single variable of type ILevel instead of one for each level class.